# How can I search the Internet for sites containing keywords in HTML (not text)?

Tags: internet, search, html, web-crawler

I want to search the Internet for sites using a certain widget.

Google has already crawled the Internet but their standard search trims any pieces of code and leaves only human readable text to search from.

Is there a way to tap into any of the existing Internet crawlers and search for keywords found within the HTML code that is NOT part of the content (i.e. text) of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Goog removed a lot of this functionality a couple years back. Hacker/crackers were using it to search for sites running particular software with known vulnerabilities then exploiting those sites.

I'm curious - What is your use case?

Comment: Market research on the widget industry. I need some numbers for a business plan and I think that's the easiest way to go about it. Do you have an alternative solution to Google?